# Has anyone seen a tutorial of building a Cocoa Touch plug-in for Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, plugins, interface-builder

Does anyone know where I can find an example or a tutorial of building a Cocoa Touch plug-in for Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't make Cocoa Touch IB plugins. There's no support for making Cocoa Touch frameworks and this is needed for making an IB plugin.

Comment: It ain't that I don't believe you, but is there any "official" notification on this? I need to tell a client that it is not possible (even if there is no documentation at all). For what I see UIView lack of the methods that NSView has on the category IBViewIntegration. Do you think this is proof enough? thanks!

Comment: This question was originally asked in 2009. Now as of 2014 building Cocoa Touch frameworks is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not seem to appear on XCode 4 beta neither... It's kind of disappointing...